# dynamicly generate xml-to-linq query filter based on combobox value C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I got a form with multiple comboboxes, where each combobox can be set to different values. Based on the combobox value I want to create a query filter. I want to iterate through all comboboxes and add its value to the filter if it dont say "All".

I want to do something like this:

```
    XElement root = XElement.Load(fileName);
                    IEnumerable<XElement> selectedElements =
                        from el in root.Elements("OrderNum").Elements("ServiceJob")
                        where
                            for(int i = 0; i < combArray.GetLength(0); i++)
                            {
                                if(combArray[i].Text != "All")
                                {
                                    (string)el.Element(combArray[i].AccessibleName) == combArray[i].Text &&
                                }
                            }
                        select el;
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just dynamically add Where clauses as follows:

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(fileName);
IEnumerable<XElement> selectedElements = root.Elements("OrderNum").Elements("ServiceJob");

for(int i = 0; i < combArray.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    if(combArray[i].Text != "All")
    {
        selectedElements = selectedElements.Where(el => el.Element(combArray[i].AccessibleName) == combArray[i].Text);
    }
}

var result = selectedElements.ToList();
```

Each iteration of the for loop, takes the previous query and appends a suitable Where clause.

For 'bonus points' you can simplify your for loop using Linq:

```
var comboBoxes = combArray.Where(c => c.Text != "All");
foreach(var comboBox in comboBoxes)
{
    selectedElements = selectedElements.Where(el => el.Element(comboBox .AccessibleName) == comboBox .Text);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved my problem :) (at least the one i asked about). However, the filters are kinda connected by 'and' statements? what if i want to toggle it to 'or' statements. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> query = root.Elements("OrderNum").Elements("ServiceJob");
for(int i = 0; i < combArray.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    if(combArray[i].Text != "All")
        query = query.Where(arg => arg.Element(combArray[i].AccessibleName) == combArray[i].Text)
}
var result = query.ToList();
```